# QWebKit for android

Tags: android, qt, qwebkit

Someone know a project  or some other way to port QWebKit component to work on android? It's driving me mad looking for a solution to this problem. Without QWebKit component I can not port my app to work on android. As alternative another kind of browser engine (native code) able to process web page offscreen would be good. CrossWalk project doesn't work for me since I need to access from C++ native code like QWebKit. Manage through C++ -> java -> C is an additional layer unnecessary. In add of this QWebKit is perfect for my purposes and export all the functions I need for my app. Not sure if blink engine can do the same...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I reply to myself. If someone is in trouble with same problem here the way to compile QWebKit for android:

[Compile QWebKit component for Android](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2015/05/compile-qwebkit-component-for-android.html)

Hope this help...

Comment: Hi, did it worked? I need the same plus a custom QSSLKey to pass to qwebpage component

Comment: In the latest versions of Qt framework code QWebKit is going to be removed but, based to the documentation, is should be still possible to get the code from repository and compile using the latest version of Qt. Personally didn't try since, unfortunately, we have to give up the idea that this component is no longer part of Qt than force to use it will involve a lot of possible compatibility problems...